# Secure chatroom script with RSA

Tags: python-3.x

Here is a chatroom example modified.

I want to be able to connect with RSA to make sure its encrypted.

But on a client machine I do not understand how to decode as the private key is supposed to not be shared.

basic field init for missing cmd params -

server_details.py:

```
def get():
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    port = 9999
    return hostname, IPAddr, port
```

what will host the chatroom and serve messages to clients -

server.py:

```
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    server_details = server_details.get()
    print("no ip or port specified: python <script> IP-address port-number")
    print(f"defaulting for {server_details[0]} - {server_details[1]} - {server_details[2]}")
else:
    server_details = (str(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]), socket.gethostname())

server.bind((server_details[1], server_details[2]))
server.listen(100) # the number of client available
list_of_clients = []


def client_thread(client, addr):
    client.send("Welcome to chatroom".encode())
    while True:
            try:
                message = client.recv(2048).decode()
                if message:
                    print(f"< {addr[0]} > {message}")
                    message_to_send = f"< {addr[0]} > {message}"
                    broadcast(message_to_send, client)
                else:
                    remove_connection(client)
            except:
                continue


def broadcast(message, client):
    for clients in list_of_clients:
        if clients != client:
            try:
                clients.send(message.encode())
            except:
                clients.close()
                remove_connection(clients)


def remove_connection(connection):
    if connection in list_of_clients:
        list_of_clients.remove(connection)


while True:
    client, addr = server.accept()
    list_of_clients.append(client)
    print(addr[0] + " connected")
    start_new_thread(client_thread, (client, addr))

conn.close()
server.close()
```

what end-users use and will connect to server, can send & recieve messages -

client.py:

```
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    server_details = server_details.get()
    print("no ip or port specified: python <script> IP-address port-number")
    print(f"defaulting for {server_details[0]} - {server_details[1]} - {server_details[2]}")

else:
    server_details = (str(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]), socket.gethostname())

server.connect((server_details[1], server_details[2]))

while True:
    sockets_list = [sys.stdin, server]
    read_sockets, write_socket, error_socket = select.select(sockets_list, [], [])

    for socks in read_sockets:
        if socks == server:
            message = socks.recv(2048).decode()
            print(message)
        else:
            message = sys.stdin.readline()
            server.send(message.encode())
            sys.stdout.write("<You>")
            sys.stdout.write(message)
            sys.stdout.flush()
server.close()
```